# How to change an input's value so it will be passed on when submitting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

With jQuery 1.10.1, I have set the value of an input field as such:

```
$('.entry input').keyup(function () {
        $('.target input').val(foo);
});
```

This works on the screen, but when the form is submitted, the value is lost or at least not recognized by PHP validation.

Chrome's inspector doesn't show a value at all:

[image]

The examples on http://api.jquery.com/val/ have the same behaviour, in the inspector, the updated value can't be seen.

So how can a *submittable* value be set via jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the `disabled` attribute.

Disabled inputs are not submitted to the server.

To fix this, remove the `disabled` attribute before submitting.

Comment: Instead of removing before submitting: Is there some other way to lock an input field for user input (as it should only be filled via js)?

Comment: @Urs: `<input type="hidden">`?

Comment: If you create a readonly field the user might be confused why it is not editable as it usually looks editable in the browser. I'd suggest either removing the `disabled` attribute before submit or to always copy the value to a `hidden` field before submit.

Comment: @Chris Then learn how to style a `readonly` field so it doesn't "look editable".

Comment: @Ian Simulating a disabled field using CSS? I'd rather not and leave that to the browser.

Comment: @Chris You mean like slightly graying the background/text? To enforce what `readonly` really means? What's wrong with "leaving that to the browser"?

Comment: @Ian Different browsers will have different methods of layouting a disabled field. Emulating this behaviour via CSS is bound to differ from the style of at least one browser.

Comment: @Chris We're talking about `readonly`, not `disabled`. You were the one that was worried about `readonly` fields looking editable. So you set their CSS to slightly change their coloring so they don't look editable.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that's what I want to avoid. Setting `disabled` means the browser will take care of making the field look disabled, taking into account the user's UI style. Using CSS to make a `readonly` field look `disabled` will not take into account these style settings and I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: Readonly is what I should have chosen in the first place. It's perfect for my use case.

Comment: @Chris These style settings you speak of are so easy to set and mimic. It's not some complex "layout" and styling. The `disabled` field has a specific behavior and visual change associated with it (not being sent to the server, grayed out), while `readonly` has only a specific visual change associated with it. It's much easier to handle minor styling than change the behavior. What happens when JavaScript's disabled? Good luck changing the `disabled` property or copying the value to a hidden field. It's

Comment: @Ian When JavaScript is disabled the entire argument is moot as you then cannot change the content of the `readonly` field anyway. I repeat my previous comment: You cannot know what a `disabled` field is supposed to look like as that is a user setting that you do not have access to.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on SLaks' answer, you could enable the input on submit:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    $(this).('.question input').removeAttr('disabled');
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I suspect that this was downvoted for its dependency on JS. I think it's a safe bet for most developers. Most of us aren't developing for flip phones.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using a `input type="text"` you could use as `input type="hidden"` to store your data. `hidden` inputs are not visible to the user and are often used to pass data along in forms.